# Deploy a New Skill from Terminal using Alexa ask command line utility

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am having trouble deploying my own skill using the aws/ask command line utilities. Below shows exactly what I'm doing:

```
$ ask new
? Please type in your new skill name:
 helpme
New project for Alexa skill created.

$ cd helpme/

$ ask deploy
-------------------- Create Skill Project --------------------
Profile for the deployment: [default]
Skill Id: amzn1.ask.skill.a49b89be-7355-486b-a915-63e7afea3d7c
Skill deployment finished.
Model deployment finished.
Create role error.
InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is 
invalid.
```

I see the profile referenced in the ask deploy command is [default]. I have ensured using 'aws configure' that the region is us-east-1, the output is json and the access/secret key I'm using is associated with a user with the following policies attached:

- IAMFullAccess
- AlexaForBusinessFullAccess
- AdministratorAccess

Has anyone else experienced and worked past this? I'm at a loss right now.

Comment: Hi,Even I am facing the same issues.I think there is some issue from AWS side for Alexa Skill set

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated your exact steps on my system and I did not get any errors.

I know just enough about IAM to get by, but I'd guess that your [default] AWS profile that the CLI is using does not have the permissions you think it does. Verify that the login specified in the [default] section of your .aws credentials file has permissions to create the Lambda. On Mac it is in ~/.aws/credentials).

This link describes setting up permissions, and how ASK and AWS profiles are related: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/set-up-credentials-for-an-amazon-web-services-account.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue.

After confirming I had the correct permissions linked by Ron, I was still getting the same error.

I deleted all the other aws profiles I had installed on my machine and that allowed the command to run successfully.

I will have to review the AWS provider chain to ensure my machine can function correctly with multiple profiles configured

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html